# Changing my class so that the ID auto increments: Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a database using Entity Framework but when I run the command `add-migration initial` in the nuget package manager console, I get this error:

> The seed entity for entity type 'Car' cannot be added because a non-zero value is required for property 'ID'. Consider providing a negative value to avoid collisions with non-seed data.

How can I change my class so that it will auto increment correctly?

This is my class:

```
namespace Heck_16365660_AspNet_Asg5.Models
{
    public enum SortOrder
    {
        sortByMake,
        sortByYear,
        sortByPrice,
        sortByMileage,
        sortByColor,       
    }

    public class Car
    {
        public Car()
        {
        }

        public Car(int year, string makeModel, int price, int mileage, string color)
        {
            MakeModel = makeModel;
            Year = year;
            Price = price;
            Mileage = mileage;
            Color = color;
        }

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string MakeModel { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public int Mileage { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public int Slug => ID;
        public SortOrder SortOrder { get; set; }            
    }
}
```

I have also added a ID = -1; to the constructor and I then get an error that reads:

> The seed entity for entity type 'Car' cannot be added because another seed entity with the same key value for {'ID'} has already been added. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

Here is my `CarContext`:

```
public class CarContext : DbContext
{
        public CarContext(DbContextOptions<CarContext> options)
            : base(options)
        { }

        public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().HasData(
                new Car(2013, "Nissan Sentra", 8995, 84574, "Silver"),
            new Car(2014, "Chevrolet Spark LS", 8995, 35304, "Blue"),
            new Car(2013, "Ford Escape 4WD SE", 10900, 70873, "Blue"),
            new Car(2014, "Kia Soul", 10900, 54691, "White"),
            new Car(2013, "Hyundai Tucson AWD", 11900, 72115, "Green"),
            new Car(2018, "Nissan Versa", 11900, 44013, "Red"),
            new Car(2015, "Chevrolet Equinox AWD LS", 11900, 94401, "Silver"),
            new Car(2015, "Kia Sedona LX", 11900, 72751, "Red"),
            new Car(2016, "Hyundai Veloster", 11900, 49369, "White"),
            new Car(2011, "Cadillac DTS Luxury", 12900, 76443, "White"),
            new Car(2014, "Chevrolet Malibu LS w/ PROTECTION PACKAGE", 12900, 28232, "Blue"),
            new Car(2018, "Nissan Sentra", 13900, 37665, "White"),
            new Car(2014, "Subaru Crosstrek 2.0i Premium", 13900, 65360, "Tan"),
            new Car(2017, "Hyundai Elantra Sedan", 13900, 29059, "Blue"),
            new Car(2017, "Hyundai Elantra Sedan w/ CARGO PACKAGE", 14900, 25474, "White"),
            new Car(2016, "Dodge Grand Caravan SXT", 14900, 70812, "Black"),
            new Car(2016, "Jeep Cherokee 4WD Sport", 14900, 73122, "Silver"),
            new Car(2017, "Chevrolet Cruze LT Sedan", 14900, 20560, "Red"),
            new Car(2017, "Hyundai Elantra Sedan", 14900, 24851, "Red"),
            new Car(2014, "Cadillac CTS Sedan w/ SEATING PACKAGE", 14900, 69141, "Black"),
            new Car(2016, "Dodge Grand Caravan SXT", 15495, 70133, "White"),
            new Car(2017, "Nissan Altima", 15900, 14808, "Gray"),
            new Car(2017, "Chevrolet Trax AWD LS", 15900, 21027, "Silver"),
            new Car(2016, "Nissan Rogue AWD w/ SV PREMIUM PACKAGE", 15900, 53087, "Red"),
            new Car(2019, "Chevrolet Sonic LT Sedan w/ RS PACKAGE", 15900, 2928, "White"),
            new Car(2017, "Dodge Grand Caravan SXT", 15900, 68671, "Gray"),
            new Car(2016, "Buick Encore FWD Convenience", 15900, 17734, "Red"),
            new Car(2016, "Buick Encore AWD", 15900, 40059, "Gray"),
            new Car(2008, "Jeep Wrangler 4WD Sahara", 15900, 71164, "Silver"),
            new Car(2016, "Chevrolet Malibu LT", 15900, 42687, "Silver"),
            new Car(2017, "Hyundai Sonata SE", 15900, 30066, "Red"),
            new Car(2017, "Nissan Altima", 15900, 52533, "Gray"),
            new Car(2018, "Ford Focus SE Hatchback", 15900, 8040, "Yellow"),
            new Car(2015, "Honda Civic Si Coupe", 15900, 76904, "Blue"),
            new Car(2013, "Ford Explorer 4WD", 15900, 61089, "Black"),
            new Car(2017, "Nissan Altima", 16495, 30478, "White"),
            new Car(2013, "Cadillac XTS Luxury", 16900, 64693, "Silver"),
            new Car(2017, "Ford Fusion SE", 16900, 29494, "White"),
            new Car(2018, "Nissan Altima", 16900, 36416, "Red"),
            new Car(2019, "Nissan Sentra", 16900, 8749, "Blue"),
            new Car(2016, "Dodge Grand Caravan SE", 16900, 38075, "Red"),
            new Car(2017, "Chevrolet Equinox AWD LS", 16900, 35675, "Black"),
            new Car(2016, "GMC Terrain AWD SLE w/ SLE-1", 16900, 34019, "Red"),
            new Car(2016, "Hyundai Santa Fe AWD Sport w/ OPTION GROUP 03", 17495, 62375, "Blue"),
            new Car(2017, "Chevrolet Equinox AWD LT w/ CONVENIENCE PACKAGE", 17900, 37334, "Silver"),
            new Car(2016, "Buick Encore AWD Premium", 17900, 49013, "White"),
            new Car(2015, "Honda CR-V AWD EX-L", 17900, 73227, "Silver"),
            new Car(2016, "MAZDA CX-3", 17900, 45925, "Blue"),
            new Car(2016, "Hyundai Tucson AWD", 17900, 32063, "Orange"),
            new Car(2015, "Toyota RAV4", 17900, 69173, "Red"));
        }
}
```

Thank You for your help

Comment: are you creating a new table or updating an existing one?

Comment: I'm creating a table

Comment: Can you show some code in your dbContext. It seems you are trying to seed (migrate) data

Comment: I have added my CarContext above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add a distinct negative value for each ID for each item you are inserting at the beginning. Like -1,-2,-3 .

You may consider using `Guid` instead of int for ID. You can use `Guid.NewGuid();` in the constructor to set new ID.

Comment: So I just needed to manually add the id numbers in sucession 1,2,3

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve the problem would be in you HasData override, instead of instantiating a new Car (which does not explicitly set the Id property) instantiate an anonymous object instead. Then you'll be able to explicitly set the ID property of your seed data to any positive or negative integer you want:

```
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);


            modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().HasData(
                new { ID = 1, Year = 2013, MakeModel = "Nissan Sentra", Price = 8995, Mileage = 84574, Color = "Silver"}, // and the rest
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the `[key`] and `[DatabaseGenerated]`
then the entity-framework will auto set the `ID` as `Key`

Comment: When I do that the error message says: "
The seed entity for entity type 'Car' cannot be added because a non-zero value is required for property 'ID'. Consider providing a negative value to avoid collisions with non-seed data.
The seed entity for entity type 'Car' cannot be added because a non-zero value is required for property 'ID'. Consider providing a negative value to avoid collisions with non-seed data."